# Connect with a linked server in SQL Server for remote MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server

How can i connect from SQL server 2012 database to a MySQL remote database?
The source DB is located in an internal domain of our enterprise and the target DB is located in external one.
Is posible to make this with linked server?

Thanks
Jorge

Comment: You may find more help in superuser site.

Comment: Did you read this? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4577/create-a-linked-server-to-mysql-from-sql-server/

Comment: but can connect to a remote database that is hosted outside my enterprise domain?